# Amcharts add Euro symbol to value in balloon

Tags: amcharts

This is my Json response, I can't figure out how I can add Euro symbol to my values. Ofcourse this is an idea of response and not the actual array that is being sent.

```
{"graphAxis":[{"valueAxis":"v0","lineColor":"#00969e","bullet":"round","bulletBorderAlpha":1,"bulletSize":"8","bulletBorderThickness":1,"bulletColor":"#FFFFFF","lineThickness":"2","hideBulletsCount":"50","title":"Prolongatie brandstoftermijn","valueField":"Prolongatie brandstoftermijn","costTypeId":15,"useLineColorForBulletBorder":true}],"dataProvider":[{"Prolongatie brandstoftermijn":4163.82,"date":"2016-01-01"},{"Prolongatie brandstoftermijn":7297.77,"date":"2016-02-01"},{"Prolongatie brandstoftermijn":7297.77,"date":"2016-03-01"},{"Prolongatie brandstoftermijn":162.43,"date":"2016-04-01"}]}
```

Can anyone provide any inputs on how to add Eur symbol to balloon text

This is my code in js file

```
//ajax request to show graph
    $("#diaplayGraph").click(function(event) {      

        event.preventDefault();     
        $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: $("#frmCostViewGraph").attr('action'),
            data: $("#frmCostViewGraph").serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                var message  = '';
                var selectedCostAllocations = $("#costAllocations").val();
                var selectedCostTypes = $("#costTypes").val(); 

                if(selectedCostAllocations == null) {

                    errorMessage($("#costAllocationError").html());                 
                    return false;
                }

                if(selectedCostTypes == null) {

                    errorMessage($("#costTypeError").html());
                    return false;
                }

                if($('input[name=reportType]:checked').length<=0)
                {
                    errorMessage($("#reportTypeError").html());                 
                    return false
                }

                showLoading();
            },  

            dataType:"JSON",
            success: function(result)
            {

                hideMessage();
                chartData = result.dataProvider;
                graphAxis = result.graphAxis;

                if(chartData == '') {

                    $("#chartdiv").html($("#noRecordFound").html());
                    hideLoading();
                    return false;
                }


                var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
                    "fontFamily": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Open Sans,sans-serif",                    
                    "fontSize":12,
                    "type": "serial",
                    "theme": "default",      
                    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled":true,
                    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
                    "valueAxes": [{
                        "id": "v1",
                        "axisAlpha": 0,
                        "position": "left",
                        "ignoreAxisWidth":true
                    }],
                    "balloon": {
                        "borderThickness": 1,
                        "shadowAlpha": 0
                    },
                    "legend": {
                    "useGraphSettings": false,
                    },
                "dataProvider": chartData,
                "graphs":graphAxis,
                "chartScrollbar": {
                    "graph": "g1",
                    "oppositeAxis":false,
                    "offset":30,
                    "scrollbarHeight": 20,
                    "backgroundAlpha": 0,
                    "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
                    "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
                    "graphFillAlpha": 0,
                    "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
                    "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
                    "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
                    "autoGridCount":true,
                    "color":"#AAAAAA",
                    "autoGridCount": true,
                    "resizeEnabled":true
                },
                "chartCursor": {                    
                    "valueLineEnabled": true,
                    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
                    "cursorAlpha":1,
                    "cursorColor":"#258cbb",
                    "limitToGraph":"g1",
                    "valueLineAlpha":0.2,
                    "valueZoomable":true,
                    "cursorPosition": "mouse",
                    "oneBalloonOnly": true,
                    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "DD-MMM-YYYY"
                },
                "valueScrollbar":{
                    "oppositeAxis":false,
                    "offset":75,
                    "scrollbarHeight":10,
                    "backgroundAlpha":1,                    
                },
                "valueAxes": [{                 
                    "axisColor": "#23272D",                 
                    "axisAlpha": 1,
                    "position": "left",
                    "unit": "$",
                    "unitPosition": "left"
                }],             
                "categoryField": "date",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "parseDates": true,
                    "dashLength": 1,
                    "minorGridEnabled": true,
                    "minPeriod":"MM",   
                    "axisColor": "#23272D"
                },
                "export": {
                    "enabled": true,
                },
                "numberFormatter": {
                    "precision": -1,
                    "decimalSeparator": ",",
                    "thousandsSeparator": "."
                },
            });


            chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", handleClick);

            zoomChart();

            function zoomChart() {
                chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
            } 

            hideLoading();          
            }
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be done with the `graphs` array, within your `graphAxis`.

If for instance you have an graph implementation like this, you can add the euro sign to the `balloonText` property:

```
 success: function(result)  {

     hideMessage();
     chartData = result.dataProvider;
     graphAxis = result.graphAxis;
     if(graphAxis && graphAxis[0]) {
         graphAxis[0].balloonText = "<b>€ [[Prolongatie brandstoftermijn]]</b>";
     }
     //...
 }
```

Comment: and what is this amount variable?

Comment: the `valueField` in this case

Comment: I have updated the description with my code and chartData is dataProvider in json response.Please suggest how to fill this value field dynamically with real values so that every value has euro symbol

Comment: not the way I wanted but you put me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: how did you want it then :)?